# Set selected option by index?

Tags: reactjs

In React, how can I set the selected option (of a `<select>`) via its index (`select.selectedIndex`), rather than value?

e.g. I'd expect something *like* this two select option "Two":

```
const FancySelect = () => (
    <select selectedIndex={2}>
        <option>Zero</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
)
```

---

You guys are still trying to cheat. I said *without* setting `<option value>`. Imagine my list of options looks like this:

```
export const options = [
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Zero"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "One"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Two"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Three"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Zero"},
];
```

Now you *can't* put `options[0].value` into the `<option value>` because it's not a string. You also can't put the `label` into the value because there's duplicates.

What you *can* do is find the index of the option with something like

```
const index = options.findIndex(o => o.value === currentlySelectedValue);
```

Now I want to use `index` to set the currently selected option. In vanilla JS, this would be as simple as `mySelect.selectedIndex = index`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use value? I've never wanted to set a drop down using an index rather than its value.

Comment: @BenCummins I can work around it, but I didn't want to limit myself to string values.

Comment: You can add value="1" etc to the option tags and then the value attribute in the select tag will use that instead.

Comment: @BenCummins Yeah...that's basically what I'm doing now. I'm using the index as the value. Was mostly curious if I could do it without actually setting the `<option value>` HTML attribute at all.

Comment: It's better to set the value anyway, because of the order of the values were to change for some reason, the values would still match

Comment: @BenCummins If I set the value to the index, that's kind of moot.

Comment: I was more thinking you would pull the options from an array or a database rather than hard coded ... I've been working in a large react project for a while and I don't think I have a single select which isn't an array in a config file or from the result of an Ajax/api call somewhere ... moving the options into a variable and giving them predefined values somewhere gives you the ability to modify them easily should the need arise int he future without having to worry what the value was previously

Comment: @BenCummins The actual options *will* be in array or config file. I've updated the question to hopefully make this a little more clear.

Comment: If you're setting the array like that, then I think he design of your data is wrong. Doesn't make sense why you would have the key of something being the result of a function call, unless the function renders the input to a unique key I guess. Trying to set a drop down by index I believe is the wrong approach and the value attributes should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you have in react, but you can always create a component that will do it for you:

```
class MySelect extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let value;
        if (this.props.selectedIndex && this.props.options.length > this.props.selectedIndex) {
            value = this.props.options[this.props.selectedIndex+1]
        }
        return (<select value={value}>
            {this.props.options.map((option, index) {
                return (
                    <option
                        key={index}
                        value={option}
                    >
                        {option}
                    </option>
                );
            })
            }
        </select>);
    }
}

====

<MySelect options={["Zefo", "One", "Two", "Three"]} selectedIndex="2" />
```

Comment: Does `selected` still work? I thought they removed support for that in like 0.13.

Comment: Right, but that's not React. React gives this warning: "Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>"

Comment: That works, but it's still "by value" :-) Also, the +1 offset isn't necessary I'm pretty sure. I started the list from "Zero".

Comment: It's a general concept, you can change based on your needs :) and no - it's "by index", not by value. double check...

Comment: You're still missing the point. I don't want to put *anything* in `<option value>` because my values aren't serializable to strings. e.g. How would you render this? `export const options = [
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Zero"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "One"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Two"},
    {value: Symbol(), label: "Three"},
];`

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of option objects. Each object has a value and a label property. Use the `.toString()` method of the symbol to set the values. Use the `selectedIndex` prop to get the corresponding value from the options array.

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/PNPL8p12).

Here is the code example:

```
const options = [
    { value: Symbol("Zero"), label: "Zero" },
    { value: Symbol("One"), label: "One" },
    { value: Symbol("Two"), label: "Two" },
    { value: Symbol("Three"), label: "Three" }
];

class MySelect extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
      
        const { options, selectedIndex } = props;
      
        this.state = {
          value: options[ selectedIndex ].value.toString()
        }
      
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind( this );
    }
  
    handleChange( e ) {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }
  
    render() {
        const { options } = this.props;
        const { value } = this.state;
        return (
            <select value={ value } onChange={ this.handleChange }>
                {
                    options.map(( option ) => (
                        <option
                            key={ option.label }
                            value={ option.value.toString() }
                        >
                            { option.label }
                        </option>
                    ))
                }
            </select>
        );
    }
}

<MySelect options={ options } selectedIndex={ 2 } />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<select>` like so (Typescript/TSX):

```
import React, {SelectHTMLAttributes} from 'react';

export default class SelectByIndex extends React.PureComponent<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement> & {selectedIndex: number|number[]}> {
    private select: HTMLSelectElement;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refresh();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.selectedIndex !== this.props.selectedIndex) {
            this.refresh();
        }
    }

    private refresh() {
        if(Array.isArray(this.props.selectedIndex)) {
            let indexes = new Set(this.props.selectedIndex);
            for(let i=0; i<this.select.options.length; ++i) {
                this.select.options[i].selected = indexes.has(i);
            }
        } else {
            this.select.selectedIndex = this.props.selectedIndex;
        }
    }

    private ref = n => {
        this.select = n;
    };

    render() {
        const {selectedIndex, ...props} = this.props;
        return <select {...props} ref={this.ref}/>;
    }
}
```